# What does "underlying field" mean in the context of groups?

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, finite-fields, elliptic-curves, discrete-logarithms

I read a statement in this [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/11518/what-is-so-special-about-elliptic-curves/11524#11524) which said "In conics, the discrete logarithm problem of this group (conics) is no more difficult than the discrete logarithm over the underlying field".

Every field is a group (in the way that a field has a group inside it) - Groups are subsets of fields, every group isn't a field.

So I am unable to understand the concept of "underlying field" of a group. If any group is a field, then all fields have an underlying group (and not the reverse) - so what exactly does underlying field of a group mean?

Comment: Where did you find this quote?

Comment: The word "group" also has its ordinary meaning sometimes, as opposed to its meaning in abstract algebra. Is that possible in the context of your quote?

Comment: @Shaun - where I read it wasn't in a public source. However, I can see similar stuff in public stuff also - for e.g. https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1941-050-01/S0002-9947-1941-0004626-6/S0002-9947-1941-0004626-6.pdf  - `It is well known that the group ring of a group of order g is semisimple, provided the characteristic of the __underlying field__ is zero`

Comment: @Shaun - I was wrong - even the original quote is public - here  - https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/11524/3941

Comment: Okay, so, I believe that the context is a group scheme, where one associates to each field a group. In this case one is given a quadratic equation, one solves this conic over different fields, and for each field $F$ the set of solutions of that equation in the field $F$ has a group structure given by some particular law.

Comment: @LeeMosher - I am not sure I understand - what does "underlying" mean? Is there a general way to find the field(s) which underlie a group?

Comment: It's not that there is a field associated to a group. It's the other way around. There is a group associated to each field $F$, namely a group structure on the set of solutions *in the field $F$* to the equation that defines the conic.

Comment: I've switched one of the tags, hopefully this will attract someone who can explain this better than I can.

Comment: Are you familiar with the group of points on an elliptic curve? It's the same idea. A conic over the field $F$ is just the set of solutions to a second degree equation in two variables; you can think of them as points on the "plane" $F^2$, just like we do over $\mathbb{R}$. In any field, the set of points on a conic can be made into a group by a geometric operation that is reminiscent of the one used for elliptic curves. This turns the conic into an abelian group. Taking a single point and the group it generates give you a cyclic group. (cont)

Comment: (cont) In any cyclic group, you can set up the discrete logarithm problem. *Some* groups have very easy discrete logarithm problem (for example $\mathbb{Z}$ has a very easy one), while others seem to be harder. A hard one is the one that uses the multiplicative group of nonzero elements of a finite field. What the quote says is that if you start with a conic as above with $F$ finite, then in general the discrete log problem on a cyclic subgroup of the group of points on the conic cannot be harder to solve than the one that uses the nonzero elements of $F$. So you don't gain complexity this way

Comment: *Underlying field* does not "belong" to `group` here, it belongs to `conic`. It's not the "underlying field of a group", it's the "underlying field of the *conic*".

Comment: @ArturoMagidin - I understand elliptic curves modulo a prime (i.e. GF(p)) - I am still unable to understand how there are two groups there - One which is the "equation mod p" (i.e the field) & the other which is a cyclic group of points generated by any generator of the group. In my mind, both are the same thing - the equation (the field) is the group of those points - it's a field which is cyclic. Or am I wrong. Unable to understand the distinction. Can they exist without each other?

Comment: The curve is defined over a field – that's the "equation mod $p$" part. The points on the curve form a group, but that group doesn't have anything to do with the field. An elliptic curve over the rationals could have a group cyclic of order three, or isomorphic to the Klein four-group (which is not cyclic), or many other possibilities.

Comment: i think you have some basic confusions here. "Elliptic curve modulo a prime" is not accurate or applicable here. "equation mod $p$" is not synonymous with field or with finite field. "generated by any generator of the group" is incorrect (generated by **any point in the curve**). Do you understand what an abstract group is? All you need is a set and a composition rule that satisfies certain axioms. Here, the elements of the group are the points on the conic, and the composition rule is a geometric rule. It is not "the field", just like a circle on the cartesian plane is not "the reals".

Comment: The first thing you should do is go learn what "the group of points on a conic" actually is as a group. And then understand that just because two groups are isomorphic *abstractly*, if you don't have a computable isomorphism between them it may be easy to solve some problems in one but not the other field. The multiplicative group of a field of order $11^2$ is "just" cyclic of order $110$, but it is **trivial** to solve the discrete log problem in $\mathbb{Z}/110\mathbb{Z}$ (which is abstractly isomorphic to it), and much harder to do it in $GF(121)$ even given a specific generator.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin - well, I have read an Abstract Algebra book twice - but this seems to be the limit of my understanding. I am not a math guy nor am I a student - just doing this in my spare time. It's very abstract - I don't think anyone who already understands it can fathom how difficult it is for someone who is just starting it

Comment: It is true that when you know a subject well it can be hard to figure out what someone else is having difficulty with. But that is doubly so when that person claims they understand the material... and they actually do not and cannot ask coherent questions because of that confusion. I may try writing something (which would be pretty long) but it will take a while. (And I may be too tired to do so tonight)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin - I never thought I understood it very well, but your comments have made me realize that my understanding is far less than what even I thought it to be. Please do write a more elaborate answer whenever you can. I will also try to go through more & other textbooks. And thank you.

Comment: @Arturo, "The multiplicative group of a field of order $11^2$ is 'just' cyclic of order $110$...." Actually, $120$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Oops; I was thinking units modulo $11^2$. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a bunch of issues here in what you write. In particular, you have misidentified what "underlying field" refers to (it's not about the group in question, but about the conic in question). The answer to the question in the subject line, what does 'underlying field' mean in the context of groups, is "nothing". But that's because of the aforementioned misunderstanding. It will take a while to explain what the quote says, and I will likely say things you already know/understand, but it is difficult to pinpoint those through comments. So please have some patience.

#### Groups

Almost-formally speaking (there are other ways, and one would define a group as an ordered list of information, etc. but pay not attention to that), a **group** is a set $G$, together with a binary operation $*\colon G\times G\to G$, usually denoted in infix position or by juxtaposition (so $a*b$ instead of $*(a,b)$, and $ab$ instead of $a*b$), that satisfies the following three conditions:

1. $*$ is associative: for all $a,b,c\in G$, $a(bc)=(ab)c$.
2. There exists an element $e\in G$, called "the identity of $G$", such that for all $a\in G$, $ae=ea=a$.
3. For each $a\in G$ there exists a $b\in G$ such that $ab=ba=e$, where $e$ is the same element from part 2.

The notion of group is extremely versatile, and instances of it show up a lot, as you know. There are some surprising ones, including [the group of points of an elliptic curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve#The_group_law). A close variation is the group of points on a conic (which I will get to below).

If we want to consider the set on which we have defined a group, we often talk about "the *underlying set* of the group", as if we had a set as substructure and we put the group stuff "on top" of it.

#### Conics

Take your favorite field; there's $\mathbb{Q}$, there's $\mathbb{R}$, there's $\mathbb{C}$; there's the field of rational functions with real coefficients $\mathbb{R}(x)$; there's finite field of prime order $\mathbb{F}_p$ (or $GF(p)$), which are essentially the rings $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. But there are other finite fields: for every prime $p$ and every positive integer $n$, there is exactly one, up to isomorphim, field of order $p^n$. [Wikipedia includes some explicit examples of constructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field).

In analogy to how we do analytic geometry on the real plane, we can do analytic geometry over *any* field $k$. You consider the collection of ordered pairs,
$$k^2=\{(x,y)\mid x,y\in k\},$$
called the *affine plane over $k$*, and call its elements "points". You can then take an equation $p(x,y)=0$ (not necessarily polynomials; any equation involving $x$, $y$, constants from the field, addition, multiplication, division, etc), and ask for all pairs that satisfy the equation. That is the "curve" defined by $p(x,y)=0$.

Note that if you have several fields fitting inside each other, say $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq \mathbb{R}\subseteq \mathbb{C}$, you can consider the affine planes as fitting inside each other, and the same equation may (if all constants are taken from the smallest field) determine curves in each of them. We can imagine the "rational affine plane" as being literally "inside" the real affine plane (it consists of points with both coordinates rationals). So if we take, for example, the equation $x^2+y^2-1=0$, this defines the unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and we can imagine sitting inside of it the "unit circle" in $\mathbb{Q}^2$, consisting of *some* of the points in the unit circle.

A **conic over the field $k$** is the curve determined by a degree 2 polynomial equation.

#### Group of points of a conic

> “Incidentally, am I alone in finding the expression “it turns out” to be incredibly useful? It allows you to make swift, succinct, and authoritative connections between otherwise randomly unconnected statements without the trouble of explaining what your source or authority actually is. It’s great. It’s hugely better than its predecessors “I read somewhere that...” or the craven “they say that...” because it suggests not only that whatever flimsy bit of urban mythology you are passing on is actually based on brand new, ground breaking research, but that it is research in which you yourself were intimately involved. But again, with no actual authority anywhere in sight. Anyway, where was I?” -- Douglas Adams, *The Salmon of Doubt*

It turns out that one can take the points on a conic over $k$, and turn this set into a group by using a geometrically defined operations.

This can probably best be imagined with a circle on the plane (as in the link you provide): take your conic, and fix a point $Z$ on it. If $P$ and $Q$ are points on the conic, here is how we define $P+Q$ (the operation here is denote $+$):

1. Start by taking the line through $P$ and $Q$; if $P$ and $Q$ are the same point, you take the tangent at the point $P$. (For conics, these can be defined geometrically easily enough, so we don't need to worry about calculus or the geometry involved). Call this line $L_1$.
2. Now take the line through $Z$ that is parallel to $L_1$. Call this line $L_2$.
3. One can prove that the line $L_2$ intersects the conic in exactly two points, one being $Z$. Denote the other point by $R$ (if the line is tangent to the conic at $Z$, then this "other point" is also $Z$).
4. Define $P+Q$ to be $R$.

It is not hard to check properties 2 and 3 of a group for this definition. For example, $Z$ will be the identity: given a point $P$, the line through $P$ and $Z$ is parallel to itself, and the "other point" it intersects the conic with besides $Z$ is $P$ itself, so $P+Z=P$. (The operation is commutative, since the line through $P$ and $Q$ is the same as the line through $Q$ and $P$, so I only need to check $P+Z$). This proves $2$. For property $3$, take the line through $P$ that is parallel to the tangent at $Z$; this line intersects the conic at a second point besides $P$; call it $Q$ (if the line is tangent to the conic at $P$, then $Q$ is the same as $P$). Then $P+Q=Z$.

The hardest part of proving this is a group is the associativity of this operation. I won't show it, but it turns out (there's that phrase again) that this is associative, and so defines a group.

This is what is called "the group of the conic."

*Added in light of comments.* The definition of this group depends on the field. The fact that intersections occur and so on is because we are in a field. In fact, one can find rational functions $f$ and $g$ with coefficients in the field such that if $P=(p_1,p_2)$ and $Q=(q_1,q_2)$, then $P+Q$ will have coordinates $(f(p_1,p_2,q_1,q_2), g(p_1,p_2,q_1,q_2))$. However, this group (while depending on the field for its definition) is *not* isomorphic in any way to the field. For example, if the field is $\mathbb{Q}$ and the conic is the unit circle, the antipode of the point $Z$ has order $2$; but the additive group of rational numbers does not have any element of finite order other than $0$. The group of points is not isomorphic to the group $\mathbb{Q}$ in any way.

#### Discrete logarithm

Consider a finite field $k$; it turns out that the multiplicative group of the field (the group consisting of the nonzero elements of the field, with the operation of multiplication) is a cyclic group; let $g$ be a generator.

If the field has $p^n$ elements, then every nonzero element of $k$ can be written uniquely as $g^a$ with $0\leq a\lt p^n-1$.

The **discrete logarithm problem** for $k$ relative to $g$ is the following: given a nonzero element $x\in k$, find $a$, $0\leq a\lt p^n-1$ such that $x=g^a$. That is, find the "logarithm of $x$ to the base $g$".

In the real numbers, we have some very fast algorithms to compute $\log_b(x)$ for any $b$ and any $x$. The same is not true in finite fields. If the field is small enough, we can just list all the powers of $g$ until we spot $a$. But if the field is very large (say, order $2^{15}$), then this is no longer feasible. We have some algorithms to make the calculation a little better than blind guessing or trying to figure it out by listing everything, but this is still considered a hard computational problem.

The discrete logarithm problem is the basis of some cryptographic systems or algorithms, such as the [Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange). If you want to *use* algorithms whose security is no better than the difficulty in solving the discrete logarithm problem, then you want the specific implementation of your problem to be hard. As computers get better and algorithms get better, a specific field that used to be "very big" will suddenly be not so big. Also, if you keep using the same field, then people can see and collect information over time, that may make a look-up faster.

Now, there is nothing special about a field. Given *any* group $G$, and any element $g\in G$, we can consider the cyclic group generated by $g$, denoted $\langle g\rangle$. If it has order $n$, then every element $x\in\langle g\rangle$ can be written uniquely as $g^a$ with $0\leq a\lt n$. So we can define a "discrete logarithm problem in $G$ relative to $g$: given $x\in \langle g\rangle$, find $a$ such that $g^a=x$ and $0\leq a\lt n-1$.

Here is where how you describe the group matters. Consider the discrete logarithm for the field of $13$ elements. This is a cyclic group of order $12$, and one of its generators is $2$. The powers of $2$ modulo $13$ seem to be somewhat random:
$$1, 2, 4, 8, 3, 6, 12, 11, 9, 5, 10, 7.$$
so if I ask you for the discrete logarithm of $9$, it will take you a second to look through the list and see that $9$ is in position $9$, so that the discrete logarithm base $2$ is $8$.

As a group, abstractly, this multiplicative group is "just" the cyclic group of order $12$. Now, you can take the integers modulo $12$, with generator $1$. There is an isomorphism between this group and the multiplicative group above. But the "discrete logarithm problem" in the integers modulo $12$ is *must easier*: if I ask you what is the "discrete logarithm" base $1$ of $8$, it is **obviously** $8$! (Here we are using an additive group, so we are asking for an $a$ such that $1a=8$).  No thought necessary. Even changing the generator (say, to $5$, doesn't get you much, because asking for the "discrete logarithm" base $5$ of $8$ in the integers modulo $12$ amounts to solving the congruence $5x\equiv 8\pmod{12}$, and we have very fast algorithms for solving these problems, even if the modulos is really big.

**Moral:** The difficulty of the discrete logarithms problem depends not only on how big the group is, but also of how we "know" the group: how it is presented/stored/etc.

#### Using conics?

Because the discrete logarithm problem over finite fields requires constantly staying ahead of the state of the art, it was suggested to instead use other groups in which the problem might be difficult. Koblitz, for example, suggested using elliptic curves because there are good algorithms for computing "powers" of an element, but we don't have good algorithms for the discrete logarithm problem in them. The advantage is that if you pick a finite field which is fairly large, instead of having just one field of that size, you have *lots* of elliptic curves over that field, so that you can switch curves and keep your same algorithms.

Now, to define an elliptic curve to use you need two things: the equation of the curve, *and the field you are using*. That field is called, finally, **the underlying field of the elliptic curve**,

It turns out that the difficulty of solving the discrete logarithm problem on an elliptic curve over a field $k$ is generally **harder** than solving it for the field $k$. So it is worth your while to use elliptic curves, because you can do so with fields that are "smaller", you have lots of options of curves to use, and you still have the security of a harder problem (as if your field were much larger).

So one might wonder if we can do the same thing with conics instead of elliptic curves, because conics are easier, and the operation on conics is easier than the operation on elliptic curves. If the discrete logarithm problem for a conic defined over a field $k$ Is generally harder than the discrete logarithm problem in $k$, then you can get the same advantages as for elliptic curves above: use a smaller field, have lots of options of conics to use, yet still have much better security than if you were just using the field.

#### Finally an explanation of your quote

What this quote is saying is that this hope is not to be. If you have a conic defined over a field $k$, then solving the discrete logarithm problem for points on the conic is *no harder* than solving it for $k$.

That's what the quote means. The "underlying field" refers to the field over which you are doing the definition of the conic, figuring out the points, finding lines and intersections, etc. It refers to the conic and its geometry; it does not refer to a random group.

Given an abstract group, there is no "underlying field" lying about.

Given a **conic**, the "underlying field" is the field over which we are doing the geometry that defined the conic.

Comment: Thank you. That was very elaborate. So we have a group of points on the elliptic curve & we have an underlying field which is isomorphic to it. Is there any special reason to refer to the underlying structure as a field instead of referring to it as just a group or an abelian group or a ring? While working with the elliptic curves itself, we don't really use any of the special characteristics of it being a field, right? Or do we? It would be the same for our purposes if the underlying group just had one operation & the basic characteristics of a group.

Comment: @user93353: "So we have a group of points on the elliptic curve & we have an underlying field which is isomorphic to it.* Not just no, but *hell, no*. First, fields are not isomoprhic to groups. Second, the multiplicative group of a field and the group of points of an elliptic curve over that field are **almost never** isomorphic. The are **different** groups. "When working with the elliptic curves itself, we don't really use any of the special characteristic of it being a field, right?" The elliptic curve is **not** a field. (cont)

Comment: @user93353: The elliptic curve is a curve. And the points on the elliptic curve with the geometric addition form a **group** not a field, and it is **not** isomorphic to the field of definition. The field is used in order to define the geometry, and to give formulas for the coordinates of $P+Q$ in terms of the coordinates of $P$ and $Q$, and you **do** need all the field properties to do that. You still are trying to identify the curve with the field in some way. Stop doing that. They are **not** the same, they are **not** isomorphic, they are **not** identifiable.